# Method Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I want to create tree-like conveyor on single context, so I can run processor's (which created in global DI container as singleton's) in parallel if they are not branched.

Each processor do some work on some fields of context, and when it's done doing it - it leaves result in context (error mark or some object, similary to service response), and other dependant of this result processors should start doing their work.

Problem is, I don't want to pass entire context in each processor, and implement some garbage in each processor to construct conveyor, so I ended up with thought of method injection solution:

```
TResult Process(*Args*);
```

I know i can brake functionality into another class constructor, but this is in my opinion dirtiest way to create this kind of conveyor, cause i will be mix-passing result's and service's.

Is there some framework to do controllable method injection?

EDIT:
Here is interface what shows how i use it currently:

```
public interface IContextProcessor<out TResult>
    where TResult : ContextElement
{
    ContextStatus GetContextStatus(IContext context);//show's can processor run on current context or not

    TResult Process(IContext context);
}

public interface IContext
{
    IEnumerable<Type> GetRegisteredTypes();

    void Set<T>(T instance) where T : ContextElement;

    T Get<T>() where T : ContextElement;

    bool TryGet<T>(out T instance) where T : ContextElement;

    bool Contains<T>() where T: ContextElement;
}

[DataContract]
public class ContextElement
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if element successfuly aquired
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
}

public enum ContextStatus
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Context not ready to be processed
    /// </summary>
    NotReady,

    /// <summary>
    /// Context ready to be processed
    /// </summary>
    Ready,

    /// <summary>
    /// Context is unprocessable
    /// </summary>
    NeverReady
}
```

The problem is i want to throw all that GetContextStatus in a bin, and make process only on a few element of context.

Comment: Could you please expand your code sample to include your actual code in order to illustrate the problem in more details.

Comment: You could try passing a reference to the context pointers etc as that would lower the memory overhead

Comment: It seams you have a sequence of processors acting on the same piece of data. You could try TPL Dataflow which is designed for problems this.

Comment: TPL seem's useful, I should check it out now.